# установка библиотеки python

Tags: python, python-3.x, library, pyaudio, termux

подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли установить библиотеку pyaudio на андроид в приложении pydroid или termux? если можно то как?

Answer (score 1):

Есть обсуждение на [гитхабе](https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/2962)
Сводится все к:

```
pkg install portaudio portaudio-dev
```

Comment: спасибо, сейчас попробую

Comment: и это не помогло, видимо всё безнадёжно